# Is there a way to check layout with selenium RC

Tags: layout, selenium

I want to check the layout of the page. Something pretty simple - that a certain div is displayed above/below/left/right of another div

Is it possible to do this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Ruby client (`@selenium` is my `SeleniumDriver` object):

To check if a certain element is above another div:

```
@selenium.get_element_position_top("firstdiv") <
  @selenium.get_element_position_top("seconddiv")
```

To check if a certain element is left to another div:

```
@selenium.get_element_position_left("firstdiv") <
  @selenium.get_element_position_left("seconddiv")
```

If you also want to check that the elements don't overlap, compare the top of the element to the bottom of the other:

```
@selenium.get_element_position_top("firstdiv") + 
  @selenium.get_element_height("firstdiv") <
  @selenium.get_element_position_top("seconddiv")
```

Comment: does this work across browsers (by which I really mean 'Does this work in IE6')?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com). It is a tool based on Selenium but with its own special language.
The idea is that you test locations of page elements relatively to each other. Here is a basic example of how the test code looks like.

```
@ all
------------------------------------
header, menu, footer
    width: 100% of screen/width

header
    height: 100px
    above: menu 0px

menu
    height: 50px
    above: content 0px

footer
    height: > 100px

content
    inside: screen 0px left

@ desktop, tablet
-----------------------------------
side-panel
    width: 300px
    below: menu 0px
    inside: screen 0px right
    near: content 10px right

@ mobile
-----------------------------------
side-panel, content
    width: 100% of screen/width

side-panel
    below: content 5px
```

For more information you can read this article [TDD for Responsive Design](http://mindengine.net/post/2013-11-16-tdd-for-responsive-design-or-how-to-automate-testing-of-website-layout-for-different-devices/)